# Problems in Unity2D Unity:NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: 2d

i have problem in Unity:NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Collectable.OnCollide (UnityEngine.Collider2D coll) (at Assets/Scripts/Collectable.cs:10)
Collidable.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Collidable.cs:24)
In these scripts (Collectable and Collidable) I indicated that if the player approaches an object, then that object will change. Please help me.
This scripts:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b62OW.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GS4Sh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your script can't find the player try adding a tag to the player and then on line 10 :

```
if (coll.gameObject.CompareTag("tagName")){}
```